# Concatenation of a dynamic integer value in a php function

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to print dynamic values and using that I will use foreach(). Here is the code that I am trying.
This is the original code for which I have to integrate it and make dynamic so that the loop runs 4 times. I have to change print_static_1_container to print_static_$i_container.

```
 <?php
    if(!function_exists('print_static_1_container')) {
        function print_static_1_container() {
```

This is the code that I am trying:

```
    <?php
 for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) {
    $function = create_function('$i', 'echo "print_static_{$i}_container";');

    function $function() {
    global $SITE; ?>

    <!-- Static 1 Container -->
    <!-- ********************************************* START ************************************************* -->
    <div class="static-<?php echo $i; ?>-home">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="gal-head home-section-head">
            <?php
            if(isset($SITE['theme_options']->static_$i_html_content) && !empty($SITE['theme_options']->static_$i_html_content))
                echo $SITE['theme_options']->static_$i_html_content;
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
        }
    }


?>
```

The error that I get is

> unexpected '.' in line function print_static_.'$i'._container()

Comment: I've counted 4 missing closing braces there.

Comment: @ADASein: The closing braces are perfect. It is working and showing the content without it being automated. That is I write, the block of code 4 times. Just that I wrote the code in short here.

Comment: What I'm trying to point is that you have to post code correctly so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
 $function_name = "print_static_$i_container";
 if(!function_exists($function_name)) {
 $function_name = function() {
    // do stuff
 };
```

You can call this function like this: $function_name();

You can use variables inside double quotes only. PHP interprets all single-quoted strings exactly as they appear, that is, the value stored in the variable is not replaced in the string.

Comment: No to mention, you must take care of the closing braces too.

Comment: I get this error: syntax error, unexpected '$function_container' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or '(' in 
>function $function_container()

Answer (score 0):

illustrate this example, might be this is what you want. Use [create_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) to create dynamic functions.

```
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) {
    $function = create_function('$i', 'echo "Calling function with argument {$i} \n";');

    // Lets Call last created function
    $function($i);
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://codepad.org/exCgKLvS)</kbd>

### Alternative Solution PHP 5.3.x

```
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) {

    $functionName = "print_static_{$i}_container";
    $$functionName = function($args) { ?>

<!-- Static 1 Container -->
<!-- ********************************************* START ************************************************* -->
<div class="static-<?php echo $args; ?>-home">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="gal-head home-section-head">
        <?php
        if(isset($SITE['theme_options']->static_$args_html_content) && !empty($SITE['theme_options']->static_$i_html_content))
            echo $SITE['theme_options']->static_$args_html_content;
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php };

  $print_static_$i_container($i);
}

$print_static_3_container(3);    // Output: Calling 3
$print_static_2_container(2);    // Output: Calling 2
```

Comment: This is the error I get in line  _function $function($i)_
`syntax error, unexpected '$function' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or '('`

Comment: Also, please check the edited question for further reference of code.

Comment: @NikhileshVaishy In this case use my **Alternative Section**. And call the function into loop.